# How to execute SQL Query dynamically in Data Flows Activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I tried creating a parameter and stored the sql query in that paramter. And used that parameter in dynamic content. But i am not able to achieve this requirement. Can anyone help me out in this context.

(i am calling Data flows activity after a lookup activity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about your exact example, perhaps you can reply with a few specifics? Generally, speaking, you would pass in a string parameter to your data flow and use that parameter as "dynamic content" in the Source transformation's query property:

[image]

In my super-simple sample, I just put my string in double-quotes as "select * from movies":

[image]

Comment: what if it has dynamic filtering?

Comment: If you're looking to make a dynamic WHERE clause if you use double-quotes, string interpolation will let you do something like this: "select * from {$tablename} where orderyear > {$year}" ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-expression-builder#string-interpolation